# AngularJS make a call to the database only after the user enters one character

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created an angular material autocomplete. Everything is working fine but now I am trying to modify the code and make a call to the database only after the user enter one character in the autocomplete box. The getEmployees function is making the http call to the database. I tried this but I am getting the error that seachText is undefined. Further on I am trying to pass the first letter from the autocomplete to the getEmployees. I created a project in Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/gLX5Tu0Jlvxh6T7HE6O3?p=preview

```
if(searchText != undefined || searchText != null) 
{
    getEmployees().then(function (users) 
    {
       vm.employees = employees
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below is a bit rough, not DRY, but it essentially works so hopefully it may point you in the right direction

```
angular
  .module('AutocompleteApp', ['ngMaterial'])
  .controller('AutocompleteController', function($scope, $http, $filter) {
    var vm = this;

    // data for autocomplete
    vm.getMatches = function(searchText) {

      if (!vm.employees) {

        getEmployees().then(function(employees) {

          vm.employees = employees;
          var term = searchText && searchText.toLowerCase();
          if (!term) {
            return [];
          } else {
            return $filter('filter')(vm.employees, term);
          }
        });

      } else {
        var term = searchText && searchText.toLowerCase();

        if (!term) {
          return [];
        } else {
          return $filter('filter')(vm.employees, term);
        }
      }

    };

    // how we get employee data 
    function getEmployees() {
      return $http.get('employees.json').then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
      }, function failureCallback(response) {
        reject("Error!");
      });
    }

  });
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/QfHaZ6b3vFW57KeKBLhx?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

in your code  **md-item-text="item.name"** is there,  but 'name' key is not there in your json..  use **md-item-text="item.FirstName"**.. it will work

Comment: Thank you. The Plunker is working as it is and it is only to give you an idea what I am trying to do. The real project is with call to the database and the call is returning around 5000 records. I am trying to modify that so the call to the database will be placed after the user enter one letter, for example 'A' and the database will return only the records with First Name starting with 'A'